# Bathroom Fan switch has 3 black wires

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan, timer

Want to swap out this fan switch for a timer. Opened it up and its 3 black wires. The replacement timer switch (Eaton PT18M-W-K) has a black/red/green wire.

Bit lost as to what connects to what.[image: Image of switch pulled from wall]

[image]

Comment: Where is the 3rd wire? Odds are really good that this is part of a 3-way switch setup. Additionally, please pull the switch further out of the wall and get a picture of the wires in the back of the box and how they exit the box. You _may_ have conduit (which brings _many_ benefits), but we'll need to know.

Comment: @FreeMan - Thanks for the reply, on the fan switch here, its 1 wire top, 2 in that bottom screw.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I had to enlarge that to realize that there are 2 wires under the lower screw. Odds are really good that this is the hot supply coming into the switch and the 2 wires there are 1) hot in, and 2) unswitched hot going out to power some other device. The top wire would, most likely be the switched hot to the fan.

Comment: Nope, you've got standard NM-B wiring. No problem with that at all, just somewhat less convenient if you ever need to make wiring changes.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the 2  black wires on the bottom are power-in for the switch and power-out to the next switch...I think I can see it hooked up to the next switch. The top black wire is probably switched power to the fan. There should be a bare or green wire for the ground which would go to the green wire on the switch.   Tie the 2 lower black wires together with the black wire from the switch and connect the upper black wire to the red wire from the switch.

Comment: Metal box is properly grounded (can just see a ground connected to the back of the box). The smart switch's ground should also be connected to the box. The dumb switches ground themselves by being screwed into the already grounded box.

Comment: @FreeMan agreed. but that pic was added after I posted my answer.

Comment: Fair enough, and you did get my +1 prior to my comment.

Answer (score 2):

A "dumb" switch doesn't care which screw/wire is for *hot* vs. *switched hot*. A smart switch, timer, etc. usually does care. Traditionally, black = hot, red = switched hot, white = neutral (with a few specific exceptions) and green (always) = ground.

Ignoring ground, there are 3 reasons to have three wires on a switch instead of 2:

- Neutral - This is quite common for smart switches, timers, etc. But not on dumb switches.
- 3-Way - That's two different switches controlling one fixture. But not the case here because they would be on 3 separate screws.
- Pass-through/shared connection - Aha! That is always the case when there are two wires on a single screw. (And also the more confusing case of a wire on a screw and a wire in the matching back-stab.) This is typically so that power can come from one place on a wire, power a switch or receptacle or whatever, and then go on to provide power to another place (a second switch in the same box, a receptacle in another room, whatever) with another wire.

So the two black wires on the bottom screw of the old switch connect to the black wire on the new switch, and the black wire on the top screw of the old switch connects to the red wire on the new switch.

This particular timer does *not* require neutral. (I verified on the manufacturer's web site, but I was pretty sure anyway based on the wire colors - if it needed neutral then it should have had a white wire.) If you replace it later with a timer or smart switch that needs neutral, add the white wire to the bundle of wires in the back of the box.

Comment: Will likely need a larger wire nut to add another wire to the neutral bundle, or a pig-tail to a 2nd bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! That appears to be a standard 3-way switch. That indicates there is another switch on that circuit. You will have to get a three way timer switch. On your switch there is one screw that is a different color (identified) then the other two. The identified one you need to keep track of. The other two are called travelers and they can be swapped. Put some red tape or whatever on it on the identified one before removing from the switch.  Also note where it comes into the box and take good pictures. The timer unit you have is a two way or standard SPST timer switch. You need to exchange it for a three way device.  The green wire goes to the earth ground, the bare wires in the back of the box. I cannot see it but I assume they are connected to the metal box and the switch grounds through the mounting screws. As we do not know what the new switch looks like I will take a SWAG and say: On the new switch if there is a green it goes to ground. The two identical colors go to the travelers and the other goes to the identified wire. Good Luck!

Comment: 3-way is what I thought at first, too. Based on the comment, there are actually 2 wires hooked to one screw (you can see it if you click the 1st image then enlarge), so it's not a 3-way.

Comment: If it is a two-way connect the Black wire (hot) to the black wire coming from the other switch, connect the Red to the black wire that goes out of the box and the green to the earth ground. This is a smart switch and needs power to operate. It may be sucking a bit through the earth ground or cycle stealing through the load. If it does not work switch the red and black. Thanks for the additional pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the tips all you legends, much appreciated!

Comment: That's not a 3-way.  First hint: they're all black (on a 3-way at least 1 would be red or white, since both travelers must be in the same cable). In conduit environments you would see more than 1 hot color in the box.  Second hint: the switch body is a little small for 3-way. 3-ways are wider.   Third hint if you look close: 2 wires clustered very close as if on the same terminal (or 1 screw and same backstab).